# Is there a way to increment each letter individually in my string?

Tags: java, string, loops, variables, assignment-operator

I am trying to "guess" a password through doing this.

This is how I am currently trying to increment it:

```
while (guess != password) {
    while (guess.charAt(j) != password.charAt(j)) {
        (guess.charAt(j) + 1);
        if (guess.charAt (j) == password.charAt(j)) {
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. Convert your string to a byte array byte[], then you can mutate any character separatelly.

Comment: If you can test the individual chars of the password there is not really a point in guessing, right? Also, `guess != password` will not work properly for `String`, much less for `char[]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force way to do just that. As noted in the comments, you can start by converting the String to a char[], but there isn't really a point since you always know the answer.

https://replit.com/@notoreous/guesspwd#Main.java

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String password = "password";

    String guess = guessPassword(password);

    System.out.println("I guess: " + guess);
    System.out.println("Actual: " + password);
  }

  private static String guessPassword(String password) {
    return new String(guess(new char[password.length()], password.toCharArray()));
  }

  private static char[] guess(char[] guess, char[] password) {
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
      if (guess[i] == password[i]) {
        continue;
      } else {
        guess[i]++;
        i--;
      }
    }
    return guess;
  }
}
```